# Qt - Hash table contains incorrect values

Tags: c++, qt

I'm doing my controller. When I click on an item in my ListWidget, the following method is called :

```
void ContactBookController::setCurrentlySelectedItem(QListWidgetItem *item)
{
    setCurrentItem(*item);
    m_window.setEditButtonsState(true);
}
```

And the `setCurrentItem()` method is as follows : (`m_current_item` is a private variable):

```
void ContactBookController::setCurrentItem(const QListWidgetItem &current_item)
{
    m_current_item = current_item;
}
```

Now, when I create a contact, I add an item to the `QListWidget`, but I also create a `Contact` object, but I also bind them together in a `QHash` so I know what `QListWidgetItem` corresponds to what `Contact`. In short, here is what I did :

```
void ContactBookController::createContact()
{
    auto new_contact = m_contact_book.createContact();

    if(new_contact != nullptr)
    {
        new_contact->setName(tr("New contact"));
    }

    auto list_item = m_window.createContact(new_contact->getName());
    m_window.clearSelection();
    m_contact_map.insert(list_item, new_contact);
}
```

Now, when clicking on a `QListWidgetItem`, I activate the edit button and I would like to retrieve the corresponding `Contact` object. However, when doing this, the `Contact` object doesn't seem to be correct. Indeed, if I use a method on him (like `getName()`), my application instantly crashes.

Here is what I did :

```
void ContactBookController::editContact()
{
    auto list_item = m_current_item;
    auto contact = m_contact_map.value(&list_item); /* doesn't work */
}
```

My hash table is declared as such :

```
QHash<QListWidgetItem*, Contact*> m_contact_map;
```

Any idea what I did wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hash has the type `QHash<QListWidgetItem*, Contact>`. So, mapping a item *pointer* to a contact value.

When you save the mapping for a specific item with `m_contact_map.insert(list_item, new_contact)`, you add a mapping from the item *pointer* to the contact. But when you try to retrieve the contact with `m_contact_map.value(&list_item)`, you look up the value for the *pointer* to the local list_item variable, which points to somewhere on the stack, and has nothing to do with the pointer to the item that is shown in the view.

Either you need to save to pointer to the selected value, i.e. make m_current_item a `QListWidgetItem *m_current_item`, or you simply use `QListWidget::currentItem()` to retrieve the current item without the need for an additional member variable.

(Side note: You should check for `currentItem() != nullptr`, since a list widget does not necessarily has an item selected.)